# How to create offline first RecyclerView in Android? And how to update only the latest data?

Tags: android, json, caching, android-recyclerview, offline

How to create offline first RecyclerView in Android so the users still can see the list when they don't have any internet connection?

I already know how to get parse JSON and populate it in RecyclerView, the problem is, users still can't access it when offline. And if I use cache using SQLite, how to update only the latest data from the server?

for example, I already got 3 data from server and populate it in RecyclerView like this:

- Data 3
- Data 2
- Data 1

After that, there is an update from the server so there are 4 data from the server. I only want to add the 4th data without load from the 1st. And its going to be like:

- Data 4 --> only add this to the RecyclerView without reload past data
- Data 3
- Data 2
- Data 1

Regards,
Elmer

Comment: Create a method in adapter, where u can pass the position and Data to it. Add the Data to the list of the item u have already in the adapter with position and then use notifyItemInserted(position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar in this project:
https://github.com/isaacurbina/MyMovies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mobileappsco/training/mymovies/Fragments/ResultsFragment.java

Basically, I use an AsyncTask to load data as the user scrolls down, loading more content (kind of like 9GAG or Pinterest do) managing a "page" counter.

Then, as I receive the data, I join it to the List object using list.addAll(results), being results another ArrayList<> of the same kind.
Then you can use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on your RecyclerViewAdapter and it will add them super fast, or you can use an animation to show them being added slowly.

I hope it helps, kind regards!